How to Troubleshoot a Vertex AI HTTP Connection Error
I am trying to connect via HTTP request to Google Vertex AI and can successfully connect for a while. However, after a few hours (more than 12 hours), the following error appears:
{
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
        "details": [{
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
            "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
            "domain": "googleapis.com",
            "metadata": {
                "method": "google.cloud.aiplatform.v1.PredictionService.GenerateContent",
                "service": "aiplatform.googleapis.com"
            }
        }]
    }
}

oauth
{ 
    "error": "invalid_grant", 
    "error_description": "reauth related error (invalid_rapt)",
    "error_uri": "https://support.google.com/a/answer/9368756",
    "error_subtype": "invalid_rapt" 
} 

oauth@access_token
The method I am using involves creating credentials within the console. I select the Vertex AI API and create credentials with the following characteristics:

NAME: CRIAS
TYPE: WEB APPLICATION
Authorized redirect URIs: https://console.developers.google.com, https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground

Then, I go to the [https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/](OAuth Playground) and select everything that is listed under Vertex AI API.

Vertex AI API v1
✓ https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
✓ https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only
Vertex AI Search for Retail API v2
✓ https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform

I choose the following items in the settings:

OAuth 2.0 configuration
OAuth flow: Server-side
OAuth endpoints: Google
Authorization endpoint: accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
Token endpoint: oauth2.googleapis.com/token
Access token location: Authorization header w/ Bearer prefix
Access type: Offline
Force prompt: No
☑ Use your own OAuth credentials
OAuth Client ID: XXXX
OAuth Client secret: XXXX


I've input the OAuth Client ID and OAuth Client Secret.
I've click on "Exchange authorization code for tokens."
I've save the Refresh Token and the Access Token.

Within the platform where I will make the HTTP request, I perform the following actions:
Create the following HTTP POST request to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
{
    "client_secret": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
    "grant_type": "refresh_token",
    "refresh_token": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
    "client_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}

Variable for the response body: oauth
Create the second HTTP POST request to https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/crias-mvp/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/models/gemini-1.5-pro-preview-0409:streamGenerateContent
Headers:
Authorization Bearer {{oauth@access_token}} 
Content-Type application/json

Body:
{{payload}}

Name response variable: JSON
Afterward, I simply extract the response from the JSON and process it.
As I mentioned earlier, it works initially, but after about 12 hours, it stops working.

I think you're making life unnecessarily difficult for yourself. The maximum lifetime of Google's token is 12 hours which is why you're experiencing the expiry. I encourage you to consider using one of Google's SDKs as not only do these include automatic refresh of tokens so that you will not encounter this issue, but you can automate the entire process and save visiting sites and constructing requests manually.

Please edit your question and include your code.   Vertex normally requires that your machine be authorized via Google Cloud CLI Im not sure you can use it directly with an access token like that but i am happy to try if you want to share your code.

Which code are you looking for? Because all the codes I used are in the post, now I just included the OAuth configuration data."

Have you considered using their SDK ?  I have been using the Node one for over a year and I don't have their issue as it deals with all the reauth steps. It should make your life easier
